# Cannot access JSON in getJSON result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My JSON is like below:

```
  {
  "statistics": [
    {
      "total_questions": 4152031,

      "views_per_day": 2198092.55,
      "api_version": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "revision": "2012.10.30.200"
      },
      "site": {
        "name": "Stack Overflow",
        "logo_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.stackoverflow.com",
        "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers",
        "icon_url": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "aliases": [
          "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
        ],
        "state": "normal",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#0077CC",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
          "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the Javascript is:

```
$.getJSON('json1', function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="'+ statistics.data.key +'"> ' + statistics.data.val +'</li>')
    });

    $('<ul />', {
        'class':'ulLI',
        'html':items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

The problem is that I am not correctly not accessing the data within statistics array and then site object? Can you please tell me how do I access data within these objects/arrays and append it to html?

Comment: This is valid JSON. Can you post the code that you use to work with it?

Comment: This $.getJSON('json1') looks rather suspicious...

Comment: @Blender: My html code is below json file.

Comment: @MarioMueller: json1 is the name of json file as how I have saved it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I used jsonlint as well and it said that the JSON was valid. I think you might've misread my comment.

Comment: @Blender: Doh! Bleary eyes this morning.

Answer (score 3):

in your `$.getJSON('json1', function(data)`

`data` is the whole object

You need to loop over `data.statistics` which is an array

```
$.each(data.statistics, function( index, item){
     /* here you access properties like "total_questions"*/
     var totalQ= item.total_questions;
})
```

EDIT: In JSON shown `data.statistics` array only has one element. If this is always true you can skip the `each` loop and use javascript notation to get first element of array:

```
 var nestedData= data.statistics[0];
 var totalQ= nestedData.total_questions;
```

If you are looking to loop over all o the properties without knowing their key, you will need considerably more code to check if property is an object , array or string and if it is object or array, recursively loop through children doing the same check and process accordingly.

You would also need to provide more detail on how nested objects need to be output in html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print everything inside site object this will work

```
$.getJSON('your json file path', function(data) {
var items = [];
$.each(data.statistics[0].site, function(key, val) {
items.push('<li id="'+ key +'"> ' + JSON.stringify(val) +'</li>')
```

what you have given as a file path seems incorrect.

Comment: or if statistics will contain more than one element run a for loop upto statistics.length and in $.each function use statistics[i].